# How to include a personal JAR with Axis?

Tags: jar, axis, noclassdeffounderror

I use Axis 1.4 and I need to use classes gathered in a JAR.

I do not want to extract them.

I try to put it in:

- `/usr/share/tomcat5.5/webapps/axis/WEB-INF/lib/myjar.jar`
- `/usr/share/tomcat5.5/webapps/axis/WEB-INF/classes/myjar.jar`
- `/opt/axis/lib/myjar.jar`
- `/root/myjar.jar`

but I still have an error.

`myjar.jar` is in my `$CLASSPATH` (so compiling works great).

Did I miss something in my `deploy.wsdd` or anything else?

Here is the AXIS error:

```
Sorry, something seems to have gone wrong... here are the details:

Exception - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

Comment: You should have more details than that in a log *somewhere*. A full stack trace would be a good start.

Comment: The log says that the exception is at ServiceSoapBingSkeleton.<init> but I don't touch anything in this class !!

Comment: "/usr/share/tomcat5.5/webapps/axis/WEB-INF/classes/myjar.jar" wouldn't work
"/opt/axis/lib" and "/root" could only work if they are on the Tomcat classpath (which is not necessarily using $CLASSPATH)
Are you trying to load a class from that "myjar.jar"? And is that class in that JAR, maybe you didn't include it or you spelled it incorrect?